# No data loaded in Einstein Send Time Optimization

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, send-email

we have been sending emails for almost 4 months.
In Setup the STO is Active. However, no data is loaded under Einstein > Send Time Optimization, as it can be seen from the screenshot.
[image]
Moreover, when I insert the activity in the Journey, the following warning appears.
[image]

Could you please help me to understand the reason why I do not see any data?
Thank you

Comment: Either your sending volume is too low, or this is one of these "please support, what goes wrong here?" times.

Comment: Are you other sends Commerical sends and not transactional sends? Also is the PSMAIN automation at the EID Running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be 1 of 4 things:

1. You don't have it provisioned for your license or you have the wrong license
2. You haven't activated it and given it the 72 hours to gather data
3. You don't have enough data
4. This is a Marketing Cloud error and you need to log a support ticket.

If I were you I would check the official documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_anb_einstein_sto_app.htm&type=5 and log a support ticket with your above details.